# Navigating through a json nested file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Need some help navigating trough a json nested file. I'm not expert on jQuery so a little explanation of how it works will be much  appreciated.

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    $.each(data.videos, function(entryIndex, entry) {
        var html = $('#name').append($('<div>', {text: this.name})) + $('#country').append($('<div>', {text: this.country})) + $('#brands').append($('<div>', {text: this.brands[0] + this.brands[1]}));
        $.each(this.brands, function() {
           $('#views').append($('<li>'+ {text: this.views} + '</li>'));
           $('#shares').append($('<li>'+ {text: this.shares} + '</li>'));
           $('#likes').append($('<li>'+ {text: this.likes} + '</li>'));
        }); 
    });
});
```

Find and example here: http://jsfiddle.net/epgBz/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're loading the file as plain string, you're not navigating a "json file", you just loaded a JavaScript object from file, and now you're accessing a JavaScript object like any other, with all the regular JavaScript rules applying: `Object.keys(yourobj)` to get all the keys as an array, and to iterate over all the key/value pairs in your object:

```
var keys = Object.keys(yourobject);
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  var value= yourobject[key];
  console.log(key, ":", value);
  // ... more code here ...
});
```

or the jQuery way,

```
$.each(yourobject, function(key, value) {
   console.log(key, ":", value);
   // ... more code here ...
});
```

Comment: my idea is to put the information I have to some graphic look. something like http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/  How would I need it to be.

Comment: That is a new question, different from the one that this is an answer to, and really deserves you first googling that and trying to find out on your own, before you post a new question of stackoverflow (generally, if you haven't tried something yet, with failing code, it's too soon to ask about it on SO).